# Install Service into Windows Server and run it only for 1 user and not for all

Tags: delphi, installation, server, service, windows-server

I need to install a Delphi Service, on a Windows Server, I need to run it for Administrator user only and not for all registered user without privileges.
The service should not be visible to other user, and the service must run even if the user is not logged in.
How can I do that?
I'm Installing the Service with InnoSetup.
Thank you in advance
G

Comment: Could you explain how the administrator interact with the service? Windows services run in a specific account and independently of any logged on user. A service has to user interface on the desktop. At most, a user can use an application designed to communicate with the service. It is that communication channel that you must design and make sure only administrator can use it.

Comment: The Service has an RPC driver that communicate with desktop app. The desktop app configure jobs of service, and after settings send a refresh to service that try to do jobs. these jobs are available only for administrator user.

Comment: OK, where is your problem then?

Comment: @Giansi87 sounds like you just need to make the desktop app run as an admin only. Give it a UAC manifest that specifies `requireAdministrator`

Comment: Thank you, I'll try with manifest.
If I want to add a user control to the service, how can I do? The service can do jobs registered but now it run all activated jobs. 
If I want to check the actual User or set a job for a specific user, how can i do? There is a simple way to know the registered user on windows server and than select a specific user to run my job?